# ubuntu - advance deleting files

Tags: file, ubuntu, delete-file

I have thousands files in format **rndstr_XXXXXXXX.jpg** where 'xxx' is unixtime (1388415305).
Now I need to delete all files older than some date.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
perl -e 'unlink grep { ($d) = /_([0-9]+)\.jpg/ and $d < XXXXXX } glob "*_*.jpg"'
```